# Selection of argument within a function based on the comparison of two vectors

Tags: r, function, arguments, comparison, matching

Given is a dataframe with the vectors x1 and y1:

```
x1 <- c(1,1,2,2,3,4)
y1 <- c(0,0,1,1,2,2)
df1 <- data.frame(x1,y1)
```

Also, I have a dataframe with the different values from the vector y1 and a corresponding probability:

```
y <- c(0,1,2)
p <- c(0.1,0.6,0.9)
df2 <- data.frame(y,p)
```

The following function compares a given probability (p) with a random number (runif(1)). Based on the result of the comparison, the value of df$x1 changes and is stored in df$x2 (for each value of x1 a new random number has to be drawn):

```
example_function <- function(x,p){
   if(runif(1) <= p) return(x + 1)
   return(x)
}

set.seed(123)
df1$x2 <- unlist(lapply(df1$x1,example_function,0.5))

> df1$x2
[1] 2 1 3 2 3 5
```

Here is my problem: In the example above I chose 0.5 for the argument "p" (manually). Instead, I would like to select a probability p from df2 based on the values for y1 associated with x1 in df1. Accordingly, I want p in

```
df1$x2 <- unlist(lapply(df1$x1,example_function,p))
```

to be derived from df2.

For example, df$x1[3], which is a 2, belongs to df$y1[3], which is a 1. df2 shows, that a 1 for y is associated with p = 0.6. In that case, the argument p for df1$x1[3] in "example_function" should be 0.6. How can this kind of a query for the value p be integrated into the described function?

Comment: could you please share the desired output of `df1$x2`?

Comment: @Antonis, the desired output is the result of a random experiment within "example_function". The output should represent an update of the vector x1 to x2, whereby changes of x1 to x2 occur as a result of the random experiment and the given probability.

Comment: @C.F, the point is that more coding examples on stack overflow are solved by providing sample data and examples of desired result, and less by description. Also the act of creating the example output tightens the description of requirements. If there is randomness, setting seed makes it reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve the problem is working with "merge" and "mapply" instead of "lapply":

```
df_new <- merge(df1, df2, by.x = 'y1', by.y = 'y')
set.seed(123)
df1$x2 <- mapply(example_function,df1$x1,df_new$p)

> df1
  x1 y1 x2
1  1  0  1
2  1  0  1
3  2  1  3
4  2  1  2
5  3  2  3
6  4  2  5
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to do anything complicated here. You can get what you want using vector-expressions.

To pick your probabilities given `p` and `y1`, simply subscript:

```
> p[y1]
[1] 0.1 0.1 0.6 0.6
```

and then pick your `x2` from `x1` and the sample like this:

```
> ifelse(runif(1) <= p[y1], x1, x1 + 2)
[1] 3 4 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df1$x2 <- unlist(lapply(df1$x1, 
                        function(z) {
                          example_function(z, df2$p[df2$y == df1$y1[df1$x1 == z][1])
                          }))

df1

#   x1 y1 x2
# 1  1  0  1
# 2  2  0  2
# 3  3  1  4
# 4  4  1  4
# 5  5  2  6
# 6  6  2  7
```

Comment: Thanks for the post, this solution works great for my example above. That's exactly what I wanted. However, this solution does not seem to work if vector x1 contains several equal values (eg x1 <- c (1,1,2,2,3,4) instead of x1 <- c (1,2,3,4,5,6)). This is my bad, drawing up my example I did not think that makes a difference. Is there a way to take this into account?

Comment: Edit to add index [1]. NOTe: i haven't actually tested this change, but the dea is since everything is a vector you can select the first of any duplicates (assuming thats your rule)

Comment: Thanks for your edit, at first glance, this seems to work. But this approach implies that every same value for x has the same probability, right? However, there are also same x-values, which have different y-values and thus also different p-values. For example for df1: "x1 <- c(1,1,2,2) and y1 <- c(5,6,1,6)" and for df2: "y <- c(1,5,6) and p <- c(0.2,0.5,0.9)". So adding index [1] is no solution.

Comment: An addition: In the example in my comment above, x1[1] = 1 belongs to y1[1] = 5. That 5 for y1 implies p = 0.2. On the other hand, x1[2] is also = 1, but belongs to y1[2] = 6. This implies a p = 0.9.